# Understanding the Web API request lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have created my own custom `HttpControllerTypeResolver` and `AssembliesResolver` in a *Web API2* project. Am I right in saying that they are only called once at startup and then cached. For example if I have the following

```
public class MyAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        MyDebugger.LogDebugMessage("In My AssembliesResolver...");

        return base.GetAssemblies();
    }
}
```

Can I force the API pipeline to call it on every request. I dont have real use case for this, just trying to master everything that happens in the API request/response pipeline. [Full implementation here](https://www.codingcurve.com/snippet/585/understanding-asp-net-web-api-request-lifecycle/) of what I have so far

Comment: You can see the source here: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultAssembliesResolver.cs

Comment: Never thought of checking the source, thanks Mike